# AngularJS: Use Ctrl $scope inside a modal with its own $scope

Tags: angularjs

I have a modal which popup when deleting

I want to assign controller scope to some temp variable and use it in the "then" method

```
$scope.confirm = param1 => $deleteModal
            .open({
                template: deleteModal,
                tempScope: $scope,
                controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
                    delete.confirm()
                        .then(() =>{
                            tempScope.someMethod() // Exception: tempScope undefined
                         })  
                    }
             });
```

tempScope is "undefined" and I cannot use someMethod() of $scope

Comment: I provided a solution. But I'm now wondering, does your modal allow for passing parameters to be injected into the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `$scope` because that refers to the inner one injected into `controller`. Pull `tempScope` outside of the whole thing:

```
let tempScope = $scope;

scope.confirm = param1 => $deleteModal
            .open({ ... });
```

I think you can then remove `tempScope: $scope` from the object.

Comment: can I do something like this `scope.confirm = (param1, tempScope = $scope) => $deleteModal`. So, the tempScope is limited to only confirm()